# Delete specific symbols (unicode) from Pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, char

I have DataFrame (pandas):

```
data1 = pandas.DataFrame(['привет, Вася', 'как дела?', 'уиии!!'])
```

As you see it contains unicode symbols (cyrillic):

```
>>> data1
              0
0  привет, Вася
1     как дела?
2        уиии!!
```

**I try to delete all specific symbols from dataframe column.**
I tryied:

```
data1.apply(replace ???)
data1[0].replace()
```

and even something with lambda.
But I dont know how to call `replace` correctly. So as I want to show all symbols must be deleted by range:

```
x in '!@#$%^&*()'
```

or

```
if chr(x) not in range(1040,1072) # chr() of cyrillic
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Anything that is not cyrillic?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , no, I want next: `['привет Вася' , 'как дела' , 'уиии' ] `. Delete all specific symbols (as !@#$'"). And I want to show them in some usable view (for example using `range`)

Comment: Sorry? I didn't understand.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, could you define `specific symbols` or better yet post your desired output?

Comment: @MaxU yep, I want to define them in some usable view. For example: `if ord(x) in range(0-64) or x in range(91-96)` then delete them

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry, that was missclick enter :) I edited previous comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unicode RegEx `(?u)`:

Source DF:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                        col
0              привет, Вася
1                 как дела?
2              уиии 23 45!!
3  давай Вася, до свидания!
```

Solution (removing all digits, all trailing spaces and all non-characters, except spaces and question mark):

```
In [36]: df.replace(['\d+', r'(?u)[^\w\s\?]+', '\s*$'], ['','',''], regex=True)
Out[36]:
                      col
0             привет Вася
1               как дела?
2                    уиии
3  давай Вася до свидания
```

[RegEx explained ...](https://regex101.com/r/H2Vu32/1/)

Comment: Velikolepno! Can you please clarify, what `(?u)` and `\w\s` mean? And how to delete all specific symbols exept `?` ?

Comment: `(?u)` is new to me

Comment: just last question: how to delete numbers 0-9 too?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, i've extended my answer - please check...

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, you are welcome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Okay, IIUC, use `string.punctuation` and perform replacement with `replace` -

```
import string
data1.replace(r'[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '', regex=True)

             0
0  привет Вася
1     как дела
2         уиии
```

Where,

```
string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

---

If you want to exclude a particular character / set of chars, here's one way to do it, using `set.difference` -

```
c = set(string.punctuation)
p_to_exclude = ['?', ...]

c = c.difference(p_to_exclude)
```

Now, you can use `c` as before -

```
data1.replace(r'[{}]'.format(re.escape(''.join(c))), '', regex=True)
             0
0  привет Вася
1    как дела?
2         уиии
```

Another thing here is to use `re.escape`, because `[` and `]` are considered metacharacters, and need to be escaped.

Comment: Awesome! So can I use `data1[0].replace` to replace just one column? Can you please clarify a bit your answer. What is mean `r''`? And one more detail - what if I want delete all the punctuations exept `?` for exampl?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam “r” is the raw string. If you want to perform replacement on one column, you can index it with iloc or [..] and the call replace or str.replace. Also, if you want to exclude a particular character, you can use str.replace on the punctuation string.

Comment: It’s considered good practice to use raw strings, especially with regex.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Okay, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your looking for substitution, `[!@...]` here is equivalent to `(! or @...)` i.e :

```
data1[0].str.replace('[!@#$%^&*()]','')

0    привет, Вася
1       как дела?
2            уиии
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If you to replace the puntuations all across the dataframe then go for

```
 data1.replace('[!@#$%^&*()]','',regex=True)
```

Based on the comment, the regex you might be looking for

```
data1.replace('[^\w\s]','',regex=True)
```

Comment: Nice, but `str.replace` works on one column at a time. I'm guessing you'd want `replace`?

Comment: I dont think one could have data strings all over the dataframe .

Comment: Yep you are right I need to work on just several columns. Can you please clarify, what `\w\s` mean? And in first your method - what if I want to delete `[` and `]` symbols too?

Comment: Use the escape character like `\[`, and `^` is not,  `\w` is the for only letters and numbers , all special characters will be neglected , `\s` is for space. Im removing everything other than `\w` and `\s`

Comment: Thank you for clarification! One more question, if you let: how to delete numbers 0-9 too?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I forgot you have characters other than english alphabets. MaxU already edited his answer for that.

Comment: Thank you for help!